# how to add a label text (dynamically) to a literal in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-literal

I want to add some controls to my form dynamically.

in html side:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal_news" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

my code in c# (code behind) is like below:

```
string str_contxt = "hi dear user!";
img2.ImageUrl = "~/images/a.jpg";

Literal_news.Text += "<article style=\"position: relative; height: 300px; opacity: 1;\"> <div class=\"banner-wrap\"> <div class=\"slider-left\"> <img src =\" " + img2.ImageUrl + " \"  alt=\"\"/> </div> <div class=\"slider-left\"> <asp:Label ID=\"Label1\" runat=\"server\" Text=\" " + str_contxt + " \"></asp:Label> </div> <div class=\"clear\"></div></div></article> ";
```

the image is shown correct (`img2.ImageUrl`), but the text isn't shown(`str_contxt`). what is the problem ?

{I used label instead of literal control. but the problem didn't solve.}

Comment: It could be malformed html...I suspect that if you look at the generated html source, the problem may become clear.

Comment: I don't think you can add asp element as text. why don't you use html label `"<label>" + str_contxt + "</label>"`